# AWS SES Email reply call the node api

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am developing an application on Nodejs-MongoDB and using AWS SES as mail server. In one case, the application has to send  email to the user what I did perfectly using nodemailer plugins. But If the user replies on that mail, it will save to my database. I already created an api in nodejs which save the reply in database.

But I need to know the procedure how the replied mail calls my api with replied information.

I found AWS SES Receipt rule where one can set the  rule for the receipt mail. Is there any proper approach to reach my requirement?

Comment: I know it's been 8 yrs, but I am stuck in the problem. @fyasir how did you tackle this problem.